# jQuery loop with val() counts wrong

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with an order form to order products online. I'm having multiple products within different categories. Furniture and electricity, for example. Within furniture category, I have three products with an `input type="number"`, with `data-price` attribute where price is filled in (products are being pulled out of a database), so everything will be filled in automatically.

What goes wrong is the calculation of input value. I have this snippet below, which exactly shows the problem. When you select 1 for the first product, it correctly shows 25.50, but when you'll up the quantity by one extra, it has value = 2. Then the price shows 76.50... So that goes wrong.

Can anybody help me to fix this problem so that the right amount is being calculated?

Thanks in advance!

```js
var furnitureTotal = 0;

$("#furnituretotal").html(furnitureTotal.toFixed(2));

function getFurnitureProductsTotal(className) {
 var furnitureProducts = $('.' + className);
     
 furnitureProducts.each(function() {
  var price = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
  var number = $(this).val();
  furnitureTotal += price * number;
 });
     
 $("#furnitureamount").val(furnitureTotal.toFixed(2));
 $("#furnituretotal").html(furnitureTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <img src="/uploads/products/product-table.jpg" alt="Product image">
 <strong>Table</strong><br>
 &euro; 25.50<br>
 <input type="number" class="orderinputsfurniture" name="5" data-price="25.50" onchange="getFurnitureProductsTotal('orderinputsfurniture')" value="0" min="0" max="10" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="product">
  <img src="/uploads/products/product-1512-individualshelfwidth:100cmdepth:30cm.jpg" alt="Product image">
 <strong>1512 - Individual Shelf Width: 100cm Depth: 30cm</strong><br>
 &euro; 20<br>
 <input type="number" class="orderinputsfurniture" name="8" data-price="20" onchange="getFurnitureProductsTotal('orderinputsfurniture')" value="0" min="0" max="10" />
</div>
<br><br><br>
<input type="text" id="furnitureamount" name="furnitureamount" value="0">
```

Comment: `var furnitureTotal = 0;` is initialized outside your function so it will be never set to zero when you determine price with `var furnitureTotal = 0;`

Comment: When you pass your value from 1 to 2, your furnitureTotal is not equal to 0 and your new add to your old. You must reinitialize in the function. (Hope it's clear)

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to reset `furnitureTotal` to `0` everytime your `getFurnitureProductsTotal` function runs :

```js
var furnitureTotal = 0;

$("#furnituretotal").html(furnitureTotal.toFixed(2));

function getFurnitureProductsTotal(className) {
  var furnitureProducts = $('.' + className);
  furnitureTotal = 0;

  furnitureProducts.each(function() {
    var price = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
    var number = $(this).val();
    furnitureTotal += price * number;
  });

  $("#furnitureamount").val(furnitureTotal.toFixed(2));
  $("#furnituretotal").html(furnitureTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <img src="/uploads/products/product-table.jpg" alt="Product image">
  <strong>Table</strong><br> &euro; 25.50<br>
  <input type="number" class="orderinputsfurniture" name="5" data-price="25.50" onchange="getFurnitureProductsTotal('orderinputsfurniture')" value="0" min="0" max="10" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="product">
  <img src="/uploads/products/product-1512-individualshelfwidth:100cmdepth:30cm.jpg" alt="Product image">
  <strong>1512 - Individual Shelf Width: 100cm Depth: 30cm</strong><br> &euro; 20<br>
  <input type="number" class="orderinputsfurniture" name="8" data-price="20" onchange="getFurnitureProductsTotal('orderinputsfurniture')" value="0" min="0" max="10" />
</div>
<br><br><br>
<input type="text" id="furnitureamount" name="furnitureamount" value="0">
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need! The answer was so simple, haha. Super thanks!!